# subversion branches with multiple Scrum teams

Tags: c#, svn, project-management, repository, scrum

So we have varying opinions on how to deal with our source in regard to parallel Scrum teams sprints. The background info is we have two 7 man teams working on the same baseline of code in 2 week iterations towards the same product release.

Team A: In one camp we have the preferred approach being: Each team work in its own branch and at the end of each sprint if the changes are acceptable then merge to the trunk. The reason is team A doesn't want to risk having bad code introduced from team B.

Team B: In the other camp we have the preferred approach being: Both teams work in the trunk, check in small working changesets early and often and rely on the continuous integration build to prevent and identify broken builds early. Team B does not want to perform large merges every few weeks.

Thoughts? Is either approach more valid than the other? Is there a 3rd approach neither team has recommended?

Edit: Just to clarify both teams want CI, but Team A would have a multiple nightly builds, one for each branch. Team B is in favor of a single build on the single branch.

Thanks~

Comment: Team b has the right idea with a CI box.  Thats more or less the whole point of CI

Comment: Consider community wiki?  This sounds somewhat subjective.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [project management is now off-topic on Stack Overflow](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343829/is-stack-overflow-an-appropriate-website-to-ask-about-project-management-issues/343841#343841). Ask these questions on [SoftwareEngineering.SE](//softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) and [ProjectManagement.SE](//pm.stackexchange.com/) instead. (You can also flag for moderator intervention to have this question migrated.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In any normal case with people involved the merging will soon be postponed "until we've stabilized this one thing". This one thing rarely gets stabilized very soon, so the branches start diverging. It's not bad in the beginning, but soon you'll notice that you'll have merging and stabilizing sprints going on. This is what's happened in all projects I've seen branches being used for something like this.

Of the two options above, I would suggest biting the bullet right away, and using option B. It will generate some overhead, but at least people end up merging their changes immediately when they still remember what and why they are doing things. In a couple of weeks, it'll be much harder.

Solution C could be to extract a third project with the common code for both teams, leaving the actively developed parts for each team to modify at will. The shared code base should hopefully be more stable. Don't know if such a solution would work in your case.

Answer (score 2):

Team B. You're introducing overhead -- the large merges -- for the purpose of avoiding a hypothetical situation ("bad code") that won't occur often, and if it does, will cause less work to correct than all of the merges will accumulate. Also, these merges themselves may introduce errors.

In short, you're adding more work to deal with an unproven problem which in the end might cause yet more work.

On the other hand, if team B (or A for that matter) is checking in bad code, the place to catch it is in the CI, and if they *are* introducing bad code, that's a management problem, not a procedural problem.

Answer (score 2):

Why not let Team B work on the trunk and Team A on a branch?  Everyone gets what they want! (just kidding: this is really no different from approach A)

Seriously, though, you are trying to choose between "work in silos" and "have only one huge team" (or more diplomatically: "stable workspaces" and "proactive collaboration").  **I would suggest a hybrid approach.**  But I also agree with Kai Inkinen's idea to refactor the codebase into shared vs team-specific code.  Your teams are large enough that the code they generate will be significant: more components makes sense and might avoid this issue altogether.  Assuming you don't have that option:

Some disadvantages of A:

- (think: what's the trunk going to look like at the end of week 2?  How confident will you feel about that code?)
- encourages "big crunch" merges near the end of a sprint (**in fact you are planning on it!**).  Expect conflicts, duplicated effort, and sub-optimal code structure after the merge.
- prevents a team from taking advantage of good changes made by the other team
- at the end of the sprint: who gets to merge to trunk first?  That team might as well have been on the trunk all along!

Some disadvantages of B:

- (think: Team B wants to share changes among themselves that aren't good enough for the trunk yet.  **You know this will happen**, or else why are there two teams at all?)
- discourages frequent checkins
- encourages "working copy transfers"
- whenever someone from Team B "breaks" the codebase, Team A will say "I told you so"

My suggested approach:

- have both teams use separate branches, to encourage frequent checkins for each team.  Checkins are *good*.  (If a team (A) wants to keep their code protected, they will find ways to achieve the same ends even if you don't give them a branch, i.e., working copy transfers: "hey Kim, I know it's not perfect, and you haven't checked it in yet, but can you send me your fix for that file?")
- have both teams "deliver" to trunk often: not just at the end of a sprint.  Deliver each "story" as it is completed.
- have both teams "sync" from the trunk often (ideally after every "delivery" from the other team).  This, in conjunction with the action above, keeps merges as small as possible and should make the end of the sprint completely painless.  Team A may resist this; they should be encouraged to "respond to change" in the code -- they'll have to merge eventually.

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html#svn.branchemerge.basicmerging.stayinsync

With this approach, teams will be rewarded (with comparatively easy merges) for checking in often *and* for delivering changes to the trunk as soon as possible.  Both of these are good things.

I should also point out that with something like git/Mercurial, you have a bit more flexibility.

Comment: +1: An alternative might be to have both work primarily on the trunk, and branch ad-hoc when they need to share something only within their own team.  But this is probably an easier hybrid to manage.

Comment: @donroby I really like your idea, it gives us the ability to have a single area without introducing the added overhead of frequent unnecessary merges, but the flexibility to share incomplete code.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go for continuous Integration. There are very few reasons to do otherwise. Check [this](http://martinfowler.com/articles/continuousIntegration.html) link by Martin Fowler for an excellent explanation of the advantages of it.